# Idhttpserver error in Delphi XE4 on IOS

Tags: ios, delphi, indy, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi Xe4 (trial) and Indy 10.5025 recompiled.
I use three components:

1. `Twebbrowser`
2. `TIdHttpServer` listening on 8088 with `OnCommandGet`:

   ```
   if (ARequestInfo.Document = '/map.htm') then
   begin
       str2 := ' '
           +'<!DOCTYPE html>'
           +' <html>'
           +' '
           +' <head>'
           +' </head>' 
           +' <body>'
           +' TEST PAGE 1'
           +' </body>'
           +' </html>'
           ;

       AResponseInfo.ContentText := str2;
   end;
   ```
3. `TButton`

   ```
   OnClick:
       IdHTTPServer1.Active := True;
       WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://[mylocalhost]:8088/map.htm');
   ```

When I click button, in debug I have the message:

> Project raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 00519D86, accessing address 0000000CC'.

Not in debug simply don't run.

How find and fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough info.  Which line is raising the AV?  Is it when activating the server, or when processing the request? Address `000000CC` is close to address `00000000`, so a class member is likely being accessed via a nil pointer, but there is no way to determine that based on this limited info. Is this problem occurring on an actual iOS device, or in the iOS Simulator?

Comment: The exception raise when CommandGet end.
Debugging I found that exact statement is: 
  function TIdIOHandler.WriteBufferingActive: Boolean;
  {$IFDEF USE_CLASSINLINE}inline;{$ENDIF}
  begin
      Result := FWriteBuffer <> nil;
  end;
Value of FWriteBuffer is "inaccessible value" 
Function is called from IdCustomHttpserver, procedure TIdHttpResponseInfo.WriteHeader

Comment: "inaccessible value" simply means the debugger cannot access the value at runtime. There could be several reasons for that, including code optimizations that prevent the debugger from finding the variable in the first place. What you should do instead is step into `WriteHeader()` with the debugger and make sure that `FConnection` and `FConnection.IOHandler` are both valid objects before `WriteBufferingActive` is called. If they are, and the code still crashes, then you can example the `TIdIOHandler.FWriteBuffer` member. Perhaps it is not a valid object but is also not `nil` when it should be.

Comment: If `FWriteBuffer` is not nil, but is not a valid object, then that would suggest an ARC-related bug in Delphi's iOS compiler/RTL.

Comment: After "SetHeaders" at statement "LBufferingStarted := not FConnection.IOHandler.WriteBufferingActive;", FConnection is valid; FConnection.IoHandler is nil.

Comment: The `IOHandler` is valid before the `OnCommandGet` event is triggered, and `SetHeaders()` does not touch the `IOHandler`, so the only way the `IOHandler` could possibly be `nil` after `OnCommandGet` exits is if something in the RTL is freeing the `IOHandler` object prematurely, which would not surprise me with all the ARC ref-counting going on.